# La prioridad y la asociatividad son independientes del orden de evaluación

Tags: c

Según [este](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) sitio:

> Precedence and associativity are independent from order of
>   evaluation.

Me confunde esto yo tenia entendido que el orden de evaluación dependía de la prioridad y la asociatividad.

Entonces como se realiza?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a usar un ejemplo sencillo para explicarlo:

```
int resultado = f1() + f2() * f3();
```

El orden de evaluación se refiere al orden en el que se ejecutarán cada una de las tres funciones. Lo que sucede es que en C no hay un orden descrito para tal tarea, por lo que las tres funciones se pueden ejecutar en un orden aleatorio (es algo a discreción del compilador).

El orden de precedencia y asociatividad se refieren a cómo se van a agrupar los resultados para almacenar un valor final en `resultado`. En este caso se aplican las reglas que se aprecian en esa página, que para el ejemplo serían:

```
A = f2() * f3(); // resultado temporal
resultado = f1 + A;
```

Comment: interesante, no había leído acerca de este tipo de cosas, solo una pregunta, si se aplica el uso de paréntesis seguirá siendo igual? ej: `int T = ((foo * bar) + foobar);`

Comment: @nikomaster los paréntesis pueden modificar el orden de asociación pero no el de evaluación